# Breadcrumb dilemma: SEO impact of linking to the current page

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, hyperlink, schema.org

I am updating the breadcrumb module of a commerce website, implementing Schema.org. My dilemma is about showing the last page:

- Product name on breadcrumb or not?
- Should that be an active link to the current page or not?

Example: urbanspoon.com [doesn’t](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbanspoon.com%2Fr%2F23%2F1600592%2Frestaurant%2FPoint-Breeze%2FAlma-Pan-Latin-Kitchen-Pittsburgh) link the last page, but is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Breadcrumbs are basically navigation elements. Their purpose is to let the visitor know where they are in the site and give them context. So, having the product name will allow visitors to know where they are.

A link to product name will serve no purpose and will only reload the page the user is already on and is hence, redundant. In general the last part of a breadcrumb is the current page and is not linked which is also a clue to the user that they have reached that last part.

Comment: I also like to visually highlight the current page. Sometimes just the fact that it is not a link serves that purpose, but you could also bold it to separate from the other breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right". However the widely used convention is that a. you should the product name and b. it's not a link.

In the example you give the last page is listed and linked, but above the breadcrumbs, but that's because they are breadcrumbs in search results, not on a page. Search results always have the page title (and a link to the page) as the first line of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

[Straight from the horses mouth](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#guidelines):

> In addition to the general structured data guidelines, Breadcrumb markup should create one or more breadcrumb trails without a crumb for the target page if it's possible to find the page within a larger set of search results.